# Getting weird babel code-frame error in vue project

Tags: vue.js

I am getting this error in my vue after I merged my branch with another. I tried deleting the `node_modules` and installing the packages but did't work

```
my_project/node_modules/@babel/code-frame/lib/index.js:48
        const sourceLength = source[lineNumber - 1].length;
                                                    ^
TypeError [Error]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Any idea how to solve ?